# Load Mongo `Binary.createfrombase64` field in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a Mongo collection with this kind of documents:

```json
  {
    _id: ObjectId('656f001650078dc1d50872ed'),
    created_at: ISODate('2023-12-05T10:48:54.641Z'),
    user_id: Binary.createFromBase64('MjkyMmZkYmUtOTM1Yi0xMWVlLTlkMjEtN2U2NjQwYmEyNGEw', 4),
  }
```

Here is how I load the data in Python:

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(os.getenv("MONGO_URL"))

collection = client.get_database(os.getenv("MONGO_DB")).get_collection(os.getenv("MONGO_COLLECTION"))

select = {'created_at': 1}

result = collection.find_one({}, select)
```

if I replace

```py
select = {'created_at': 1}
```

with

```py
select = {'user_id': 1}
```

I get this error:

```
...

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.11.5/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/message.py:1619, in _OpMsg.unpack_response(self, cursor_id, codec_options, user_fields, legacy_response)
   1617 # If _OpMsg is in-use, this cannot be a legacy response.
   1618 assert not legacy_response
-> 1619 return bson._decode_all_selective(self.payload_document, codec_options, user_fields)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.11.5/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bson/__init__.py:1259, in _decode_all_selective(data, codec_options, fields)
   1236 """Decode BSON data to a single document while using user-provided
   1237 custom decoding logic.
   1238 
   (...)
   1256 .. versionadded:: 3.8
   1257 """
   1258 if not codec_options.type_registry._decoder_map:
-> 1259     return decode_all(data, codec_options)
   1261 if not fields:
   1262     return decode_all(data, codec_options.with_options(type_registry=None))

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.11.5/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bson/__init__.py:1167, in decode_all(data, codec_options)
   1164 if not isinstance(codec_options, CodecOptions):
   1165     raise _CODEC_OPTIONS_TYPE_ERROR
-> 1167 return _decode_all(data, codec_options)

InvalidBSON: invalid length or type code
```

Here are the version I use:

```
Python: 3.11.5
pymongo: 4.6.1
MongoDB: 5.0.23
```

It seems to come from the `Binary.createFromBase64`.

Does anybody have a clue ?

Comment: Does [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-1165) answer your question?

Comment: But actually the validation command says everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary subtype 4 is a UUID, see https://bsonspec.org/spec.html.

The base64 string you show is 'MjkyMmZkYmUtOTM1Yi0xMWVlLTlkMjEtN2U2NjQwYmEyNGEw', which decodes to the hexadecimal

```
32 39 32 32 66 64 62 65 2d 39 33 35 62 2d 31 31 65 65 2d 39 64 32 31 2d 37 65 36 36 34 30 62 61 32 34 61 30
```

Coverting that to string gives "2922fdbe-935b-11ee-9d21-7e6640ba24a0"

In other words, the UUID was not properly encoded before being stored in the database.

The correct hexadecimal for that UUID would be

```
29 22 fd be 93 5b 11 ee 9d 21 7e 66 40 ba 24 a0
```

And the corresponding base64 should be

```
Binary.createFromBase64("KSL9vpNbEe6dIX5mQLokoA==",4)
```

Consider using pymongo's native UUID handling: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/uuid.html